# Android - Insert contact - response

Tags: android, android-contacts, startactivityforresult

Can I somehow receive a response when I insert vCard into the phone?

This is what I've done.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/x-vcard");
    startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

Unfortunately, it immediately returns `RESULT_CANCELED`.

Comment: have you get any hint over https://stackoverflow.com/a/4381866/5049244

Comment: [How to import contacts from VCF file by using code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696873/how-to-import-contacts-from-vcf-file-by-using-code/11312507#11312507)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot insert those contacts using content provider - I have to use intent.