# Download a vcard from the website and add as a contact immediately

Tags: php, web, vcf-vcard

I need to have an ability to show some link on the website: example

```
<a href="/download.vcard.php">Add as contact</a>
```

Is there any way to force iPhone and Android phone to open "New contact" system window with editable fields and a "Save" button on it?

If it is not possible to do it on backend side maybe is there any jquery plugin to support this from front side?

Is this a correct content-type set for a vcard?

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/x-vcard;charset=utf-8;');
?>
```

My question is almost the same as [How to get a vCard (.vcf file) into Android contacts from website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381766/how-to-get-a-vcard-vcf-file-into-android-contacts-from-website) but it was created 8 years ago and since that time a lot of things changed.

Comment: MIME type `text/x-vcard` is now deprecated. It's better to use `text/vcard`

Comment: Thx! Will try this out